# malloc function crash

Tags: c

I have a problem with memory allocation using malloc.
Here is a fragment from my code:

```
    printf("DEBUG %d\n",L);
    char *s=(char*)malloc(L+2);
    if(s==0)
    {
      printf("DEBUGO1");
    }
    printf("DEBUGO2\n");
```

It outputs "DEBUG 3",and then a error msgbox appears with this message:

> The instruction at 0x7c9369aa referenced memory at "0x0000000".   The
>   memory could not be read

For me such behavior is very strange.
What can be wrong here?

The application is single threaded.

I'm using mingw C compiler that is built in code::blocks 10.05

I can provide all the code if it is needed.
Thanks.

**UPD1:**
There is more code:

```
char *concat3(char *str1,char *str2,char *str3)
{
    /*concatenate three strings and frees the memory allocated for substrings before*/
    /* returns a pointer to the new string*/

    int L=strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+strlen(str3);
    printf("DEBUG %d\n",L);
    char *s=(char*)malloc(L+2);
    if(s==0)
    {
      printf("DEBUGO1");
    }
    printf("DEBUGO2\n");
    sprintf(s,"%s%s%s",str1,str2,str3);
    free(str1);
    free(str2);
    free(str3);
    return s;
}
```

**UPD2:**
It seems the problem is more complicated than i thought. Just if somebody has enough time for helping me out:

Here is all the code

[Proj](http://wikisend.com/download/131726/cbproj.zip)

(it is code::blocks 10.05 project,but you may compile the sources without an ide ,it is pure C without any libraries):

call the program as
"cbproj.exe s.pl" (the s.pl file is in the root of the arhive)

and you may see it crashes when it calls  the function "malloc" that is on the 113th line of "parser.tab.c"(where the function concat3 is written).

I do the project in educational purpouses,you may use the source code without any restrictions.

**UPD3:**
The problem was that it was allocated not enough memory for one of the strings in program ,but the it seemed to work until the next malloc.. Oh,I hate C now:)
I agree with the comments about bad coding style,need to improve myself in this.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; what is `L`?

Comment: The error is elsewhere. Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: You should compare with NULL instead of 0

Comment: @BlackBear: actually a zero comparison is perfectly legal.

Comment: All the code from the application is about 6000 lines.. I'm not sure i can post it here. I have added the function that cause the crash.

Comment: Note that the code reaches neither printf("DEBUGO1")  nor  printf("DEBUGO2").

Comment: @StilesCrisis: That doesn't make it good style. He also shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: You may use gdb to show the call stack when the program crashes (use 'bt' command)

Comment: Change `printf("DEBUGO1");` to  `printf("DEBUGO1");`. What does `printf("%p %p %p\n", str1, str2, str3);` at the top show?

Comment: @nos he allocates `L+2`; more than enough space.

Comment: malloc() will return NULL when your program has consumed all available virtual memory space or when the heap is corrupted.  The latter is by far the most common case.  It didn't get corrupted by the code you posted but by something else that ran before.  Having access to a good debug allocator is crucial to debug this.

Comment: Debugging print statements should at least end with a newline.  Arguably, they should be written to stderr, not stdout, or you should `fflush()` either stdout or 0 after writing.  Otherwise, the information may be buffered until later.

Comment: You are right.I have added newline to printf("DEBUGO1\n"). Nothing changed.

Comment: to Dave: printf("%p %p %p\n", str1, str2, str3); at the top shows 000328D8 00032728 00032860

Comment: @BlackBear: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null

Comment: @StilesCrisis: thanks. I thought they both were 0 but NULL had a different type (sort of void*) so there might be an hidden cast which screws everything up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this exact code is that when `malloc` fails, you don't return from the function but use this NULL-pointer further in `sprintf` call as a buffer.

I'd also suggest you to free memory allocated for `str1`, `str2` and `str3` outside this function, or else you might put yourself into trouble somewhere else.

---

**EDIT**: after running your program under valgrind, two *real* problems revealed (in parser.tab.c):

In `yyuserAction`,

```
char *applR=(char*)malloc(strlen(ruleName)+7);
sprintf(applR,"appl(%s).",ruleName);
```

`+7` is insufficient since you also need space for \0 char at the end of string. Making it `+8` helped.

In `SplitList`,

```
char *curstr=(char*)malloc(leng);
```

there's a possibility of allocating zero bytes. `leng + 1` helps.

After aforementioned changes, everything runs fine (if one could say so, since I'm not going to count memory leaks).

Comment: Thank you,the first problem with applR was the actual problem. After fixing it everything works fine. You are also right about memory leaks,i need to learn some tool (like valgrind?) to fix all of them.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it actually looks like your `if` statement is not quite what you have posted here. It suggests that your `if` statement might be something like this:

```
if(s=0) {
}
```

Note the single `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (equality).

Comment: Yes,it seems like the only possible answer,but everything is exactly as i wrote .I have attached the whole project to my post..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `free` on pointers that were not created by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.  From the Manpage:

> free()  frees  the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().  Otherwise,  or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

Comment: Thanks, but i use "free" for pointers created by strdup,which uses malloc for allocting memory